# Python regex : detect a word with duplicated chars

Tags: python, regex, artificial-intelligence, words

I wonder if i could detect the word '**hey**' but in this form : '**heeeey**'
How would i do that in python ?
I searched many times but i didn't find an answer.

*I want the program to get it like 'hey' at last, i want it to understand that 'heeey' means 'hey'.

Comment: Something like `h(.)\1+y` perhaps?

Comment: No i tried it and not working :/

Comment: Would this regex also make `meet` to `met` ? or `hello` to `helo` , etc?

Comment: I think it will .. but if we add exceptions to it then it wouldn't .. i found the answer in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(.)\1+')
test_str = "heeeey"
subst = r"\1"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

You can do it through `re.sub`.Here we capture any `character` which are repeated ahead and replace all by `\1` .So all the repetitions will be gone.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/7#python

Comment: It works fine, but it will be '**hy**' and it won't be '**hey**' that's my problem now. Thanks for helping.

Comment: And can you please explain that regex ?

Comment: I don't know .. i took your code exactly and the result was 'hy'

Comment: @AmrEssam `r` will disable python from interpreting its on escape sequences.